# Variety k-times of first kind

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Where is the name "variety k-times of first kind" in Serre's Algebraic coherent sheaves from? (see page 95 on [English version](https://math.berkeley.edu/~achinger/fac/fac.pdf))

Is there any geometric intuition of this class of varieties?

Comment: Did you check the reference in the associated footnote ?

Comment: Unfortunately is seems to be not available on the internet :(